# Pillow on virtualenv python 3 install issue

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

when i am trying to install Pillow in my virtualenv i get the following error:

```
>(django-project1)pk@pk-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~/Work/django-project1$ pip install -U Pillow
Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-2.2.1.zip (2.2MB): 2.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Pillow

>Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow

>    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I/home/pk/Work/django-project1/include/python3.3m -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/_imaging.o
    _imaging.c:76:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/pk/Work/django-project1/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bx7vwp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/pk/Work/django-project1/include/site/python3.3:
    running install

>running build

>running build_py

>creating build

>creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.3

>creating build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/tests.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-3.3/PIL

>running egg_info

>writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

>writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

>writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

>warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



>reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

>reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

>writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

>running build_ext

>building 'PIL._imaging' extension

>creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/libImaging

>i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I/home/pk/Work/django-project1/include/python3.3m -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.3/_imaging.o

>_imaging.c:76:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

> #include "Python.h"

>                    ^

>compilation terminated.

>error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

>----------------------------------------
>Cleaning up...
>Command /home/pk/Work/django-project1/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bx7vwp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/pk/Work/django-project1/include/site/python3.3 failed with error code 1 in /home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/Pillow
Storing complete log in /home/pk/.pip/pip.log
```

What could be causing the issue? I also have issues installing PIL separately in the virtualenv:

```
>(django-project1)pk@pk-900X3C-900X3D-900X4C-900X4D:~/Work/django-project1/shop$ pip install PIL
>Downloading/unpacking PIL
>  You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip >will default to disallowing insecure files.
>  Downloading PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506kB): 506kB downloaded
>  Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
>      File "/home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/PIL/setup.py", line 182
>        print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
>                                            ^
>    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
>
>  File "/home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/PIL/setup.py", line 182
>
>    print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
>
>                                        ^
>
>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
>----------------------------------------
>Cleaning up...
>Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/pk/Work/django-project1/build/PIL
>Storing complete log in /home/pk/.pip/pip.log
```

but it seems that without virtualenv sourced the PIL is installing ok.

Answer (score 15):

I have exactly the same problem and it is a result of the python-dev being for python2 on the default ubuntu (13.10 in my case).

To get around this you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct Command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

dev-python3 package solved the issue.
To install do:

```
sudo apt-get install dev-python3
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? There is no package called "dev-python3" on debian or ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @th0th Take it easy man =) First of all the question never says that it is in any way related to one OS or the other. I actually can't remember which one i was using 2 years ago but that might be the kUbuntu where repos were different and so were the package names. If it does not work for you it wouldn't necessarily mean that it won't work for someone else.

Comment: No hard feelings, sorry if it seemed like an angry comment. As far as I can remember, Debian/Ubuntu packages have been following *-dev package naming convention for more than 2 years. It is just surprising to see an inaccurate answer's being accepted as there are other answers that are actually accurate.